# No sound over HDMI on Desktop 13.10

Tags: 13.10, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, alsa

I have the option for HDMI and have the output set to 100% but no sound. I get sound from the speaker port on the front of my case and the back but not over HDMI to my TV. I have tried a ton of thing in CLI I found on fourms but still nothing is working.

I am running an A4 5300 with an ASUS mobo A55BM-A/USB3.

Comment: I assume the HDMI port comes from your graphic card right? So it would be of interest what card you are using and with what driver, as the problem most likely comes from there

Comment: I am using the built in one on the GPU.  I have verified the correct driver and are up to date.  In fact I was just copying commands from forums and installed nvidia drivers and had to remove them cause all I had was a black screen.

Comment: Did you try setting your Audio Device to *(HDMI)* under the Configuration tab of: 'pavucontrol' (or alternative "PulseAudio Volume Control" in the Multimedia section)?

Comment: yes still no sound

Comment: So I reloaded the OS and still no sound over HDMI.  I updated the daily dkms, uninstalled then reinstalled pulseaudio,  verified that it's not muted in alsamixer, also I still get sound over the front and rear IO ports.

Comment: I have followed these links and still no sound over HDMI can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/864735

Comment: http://learnedstuffs.wordpress.com/2013/12/14/enabling-ati-radeon-hdmi-audio-output-on-ubuntu-13-10/

Answer (score 0):

in 'sound' settings you can change the audio output to HDMI. 
You will need to change it back afterwards.

Comment: yes I have and still no sound